# (Beginner Question) facing errors when trying to install parcel.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, parcel, parceljs

I'm new to programming and facing some difficulties when trying to install parcel.js

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js

npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/parcel

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/parcel'

npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/parcel'] {

npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/parcel'] {

npm ERR!     errno: -13,

npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',

npm ERR!     path: '../lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js',

npm ERR!     dest: '/usr/local/bin/parcel'

npm ERR!   },

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',

npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js',

npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/parcel'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/cavingayle/.npm/_logs/2020-06-09T20_46_00_855Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Calvin, can you tell us about what operating system you are using? I think you should try to run this command as elevated permissions.

Comment: Hi Christopher, 

Im currently running mac OS Catalina. My apologies but how is it possible to run as elevated permissions

Comment: prefix your command with sudo;
For example, sudo npm install xxx

Comment: I just wanted to circle back to this comment two years later, this helped me get my first dev environment setup to beginning learning. Im now a Software Engineer, thanks again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cavin,

I believe that you are having an issue related to administrative elevation in NPM.

Attempt to prefix NPM with sudo in your command.

for example:

```
sudo npm install parcel
```